# sync c program with terminal in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Terminal is not synchronized with the program.

This is my simple code to see if it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   puts("Hello World!");
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

but in the local terminal appears
`Press a key to continue...`
before
`Hello World!`

This means that it is not synchronized with the program. How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the output buffer is not getting flushed before the function `system` is executed.

In order to explicitly flush the output buffer, you can add the line

```
fflush( stdout );
```

immediately before the call to `system`.

On most platforms, the standard output stream is line-buffered, so it should not be necessary to flush the output buffer, because `puts` automatically adds a newline character to the string, which should cause a line-buffered stream to be automatically flushed. However, according to the information you provided, the standard output stream does not seem to be line-buffered in Eclipse. It seems to be fully-buffered instead.

Comment: thanks, it work.

But is there a method that does this automatically?

Comment: @Christian30: I am not familiar with Eclipse, so I don't know. My guess is that this is a limitation of Eclipse. As stated in my answer, on most other platforms, flushing the buffer explicitly is not necessary, because that happens automatically whenever a newline character is printed.